# Are the green card lottery (Diversity Visa) results final when released in May?

Tags: greencard, usa

For example, from the dvlottery website :

> DV-2018 Entrants may enter their confirmation information through the link below starting at noon (EDT) on **May 2, 2017**. The DV-2018 registration period opens on October 4, 2016, and closes on November 7, 2016. DV-2018 Entrants should keep their confirmation number until at least **September 30, 2018**.

Are the results available on May 2, 2017 the same as on September 30, 2018, or they are released by quota?

In other words, if I check my number on May 2, 2017 and I find that I've not been selected, is there a chance that I will be selected before September 30, 2018 or it is a definitive result?

Thanks in advance, and if the official website mentions something about this please attach it.

Comment: No, they won't change the status later. As it is, it's possible that the visas will run out before everyone selected can apply. Good luck.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mentioned about the visas

Comment: They approve more invitations than the actual number of visas, assuming that some people won't apply or are not admissible. If you get picked, don't wait too long to actually apply.

Comment: Please see my answer--because I was wrong! I have a relative trying this year...so good luck to you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And, hey, I was wrong! I don't believe this happens every year, so you should not rely on it, but for last year's diversity visa, DV-2017, the [US government has announced](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/immigrate/diversity-visa/if-you-are-selected.html):

> Have you checked your Diversity Visa (DV) 2017 status recently?
>   Additional entrants have been added to “selected” status! Check your
>   status using your unique confirmation number on the Entrant Status
>   Check (ESC) website, [www.dvlottery.state.gov](http://www.dvlottery.state.gov).
>
> Selected entrants are encouraged to complete the online DS-260
>   application immediately to schedule an interview appointment at the
>   appropriate U.S. Embassy or Consulate.

The adding of extra entrants could be due to a mistake in the lottery process (not enough people from particular countries were selected), the expected number of applicants isn't as high as predicted, or more applicants have been refused than expected.

The diversity immigrant visa program does have a limited number of visas. It is possible for those visas to be used before someone who was selected is able to apply. You should always apply as soon as possible.

Note: there's no date on the page stating when the government added entrants to the DV-2017 approved list.